# Drupal - changing url alias programmatically for some migrated terms

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, foreach, drupal-7

I'm trying to do an SQL query in Drupal to edit a handful of taxonomy terms's url_aliases across a couple of sites.

```
  // Query to get aliases which contain event-category in alias.
  $aliases = db_select('url_alias', 'ua')
    ->fields('ua', array('alias'))
    ->condition('alias', '%event-category/%', 'LIKE')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchCol();

  foreach ($aliases as &$ua) {
    // Strip out event-category and replace with category
    $new_alias = str_replace("event-category/", "category/", $ua);

    // Update url_alias table
    $update_db = db_update('url_alias')
      ->fields(array('alias' => $new_alias))
      ->condition('alias', '%event-category/%', 'LIKE')
      ->execute();

  }
```

Each time I run this code the correct terms aliases are changed but they are all changed to the first terms alias. Example:

- event-category/abc123 => category/abc123
- event-category/def456 => category/abc123
- event-category/ghi789 => category/abc123

As far as I can tell the str_replace works when dpm'ing the $new_alias variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the update query condition to 
      `->condition('alias', '%'.$ua.'%', 'LIKE')`

Comment: Brilliant. I was wrapped around this all day yesterday and couldn't see the issue.